# What is with the Shadow Realm in Yu-Gi-Oh?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

in *Yu-Gi-Oh!*, what is the problem with the Shadow Realm? How is it bad to be sent there?

Answer (score 2):

Shadow Realm was the euphemism for death in the dubbed version. Original Anime/Manga didn't use it.

> Yu-Gi-Oh! was imported by 4kidz media, who took it upon themselves to hack away anything that could be controversial about the show, to the point where **they replaced any threat of death or violence with “being sent to the Shadow Realm.** - [cbldf.org](http://cbldf.org/2019/03/anime-censorship-in-the-early-2000s/)

But even if you ignore the euphemism part, Shadow Realm is a place of darkness so imagine having a life in eternal darkness. So of course it sounds like a bad bad place.

Comment: I understand that, but would you rather be sent to another dimension, or have a evil spirit send you to hell? (Yami-Bakura)